# Adding multiple gradients in a single ggplot barplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently, I'm creating a relative abundance ggplot with multiple biological taxa. However, I'd like to add in multiple colored gradients depending on the "phylogeny" of the taxa to delineate which Phylum each "Taxa" belongs to. Essentially, what I have right now is this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)

taxdat <- read.table("fig_2.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)

data <- melt(cbind(taxdat, taxa = rownames(taxdat)), id.vars = c('taxa'))

#order factor
data$taxa <- factor(data$taxa, levels=unique(data$taxa))

ggplot(data,aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = taxa)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Which produces this...

[Taxonomic breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj9Wi.jpg)

However, I'd like to color code each taxa based on the phylum it belongs to, yet still retain individual gradients to differentiate the taxa from each other. For example, orange hues for "Arthropoda", green hues for "Nematoda", etc. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dean

P.S. Here's the taxdata if you want it:

```
                Abund    Phylogeny
Metazoa            13      Metazoa
Arthropoda          3   Arthropoda
Arachnida           3   Arthropoda
Alicorhagia         3   Arthropoda
Araneae             2   Arthropoda
Harpacticoida       1   Arthropoda
Lepidoptera         6   Arthropoda
Oribatida           4   Arthropoda
Gehypochthonius     1   Arthropoda
Coccinellidae       5   Arthropoda
Salticidae          3   Arthropoda
Liochthonius        3   Arthropoda
Paraphidippus       1   Arthropoda
Paucitubulatina     4 Gastrotricha
Chaetonotidae       1 Gastrotricha
Nematoda           30     Nematoda
Chromadorea         5     Nematoda
Dorylaimida         2     Nematoda
Plectidae           1     Nematoda
Prismatolaimus      2     Nematoda
Alaimus             2     Nematoda
Geomonhystera      10     Nematoda
Mesodorylaimus      1     Nematoda
Prodesmodora        1     Nematoda
Tylocephalus        1     Nematoda
Eutardigrada        1   Tardigrada
Parachela           2   Tardigrada
```

UPDATE: I've altered the taxadata with the phylogeny data, so the above code will not run smoothly if just copied and pasted.

Comment: Your example data is unclear. The `Abund` column seems to contain phyla already, but the numbers don't match up with the extra `phylogeny` column that you add. Can you include a complete and correct final dataset to be used for input.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the data with the phylogeny information. The rownames column is more specific than Phylum in many cases, the `Phylogeny` column lists the Phylum to which the rownames taxonomic data belongs. I'd like to assign color different gradients to different taxa based upon their `Phylogeny`. The `Abund` data should just contain the relative abundance data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give some thought as to the most effective visualization of this data. One issue with colours is that past a certain number of categories (8 or so), they become ineffective as a means to distinguish categories. So in your case they could work for phylum, but not taxa. Another consideration: with more than one factor, you generally need more than one method of grouping factors (*i.e.* more than colour).

Define the question that you want the visualization to address, *e.g.* "I want a quick view of the major taxa in each phylum". Here's a `ggplot` suggestion to address that question. I've assumed your data are in a data frame, `data`, with a column named `Taxa` instead of having them in row names.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(Taxa, Abund)) + geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(Phylogeny ~ .) + theme_light() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Result:
[image]

You might also consider tools and methods other than those in `ggplot`. For example, another way to visualize proportions in hierarchical categories is a treemap:

```
library(treemap)
treemap(data, index = c("Phylogeny", "Taxa"), vSize = "Abund", 
  vColor = "Abund", palette = "Spectral")
```

Result (requires some refinement):
[image]

Comment: Hi neilfws, thanks for all the great insight on this issue. You are correct, color spectra probably aren't the best way to go with distinguishing the taxa considering how big some of the groups are. The alternatives you've provided are fantastic, and I'll take your advice to try something more that speed. Thanks again for all the help, it's much appreciated.